Efficient method to batch clearcut product images in Photoshop CC
Just wondering if there are any recommendations for an efficient method to clearcutting batches of products. I have to clearcut 100-200 food products each month to go in a catalogue for work. The resolution and sizing isn't consistent so it takes some manual tweaking. What I am currently doing is setting up the canvas size and placing all images into the document as layers. I then created an action for Select>Subject>Mask but end up going back and cleaning up some which is the time consuming part. I then use 'export from layers' to export all layers as individual pngs. I know there are clearcutting plugins out there that might hasten up the process and do a more accurate job, I would have to find a free plugin though. Most products are on white backgrounds.

If select subject and masking aren't working well, then it probably has something to do with how the images were taken. They should be on a plain background with sufficient contrast. You can automate by recording an action, and running the action in File > Automate > Batch.
